# Transfer WCF custom authentication session to service

Tags: wcf, authentication

I have WCF webservice that's doing custom authorization using UserNamePasswordValidator

```
public class CustomUserNameValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
    {
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
        {
        try
            {
            MySession session = new MySession(userName, password);
            }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
            {
            throw new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenException("Incorrect username or password");
            }
        }
    }
```

Authentication works fine, but I don't know is how to transfer the session created in CustomUserNameValidator to the service.

MySession, in case you are wondering, comes from third party API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going through several iterations of my web service I arrived to an acceptable answer to my question. The answer that I would have accepted immediately, had someone typed it out.

Don't use UserNamePasswordValidator. Configure your service to use Transport security, and set clientCredentialType to "None". In web service methods the first thing to do will be to create a session with credentials extracted from WebOperationContext.Current, for example like this:

```
    WebOperationContext operationContext = WebOperationContext.Current;
    string encoded = operationContext.IncomingRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization];

    if (encoded != null)
    {
        var decoded = Convert.FromBase64String(encoded.Substring(encoded.LastIndexOf("Basic ") + 6));
        var headerValue = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decoded);

        string userName = headerValue.Substring(0, headerValue.IndexOf(":"));
        string password = headerValue.Substring(headerValue.IndexOf(":") + 1, headerValue.Length - userName.Length - 1);

        if (ValidCredentials(userName, password)
           return new MySession(userName, password);
    }

    operationContext.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add(HttpResponseHeader.WwwAuthenticate,
            String.Format("Basic realm =\"MyRealm\"", Settings.EBCommunity));
    throw new WebFaultException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
```

This way the web service can easily be self-hosted or hosted on IIS, and it avoids [UserNamePasswordValidator http protocol issue](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2010/02/02/fix-to-allow-customizing-the-status-code-when-validation-fails.aspx).

Comment: I believe static variables will not help you. They will be application wide, and live for the length of the entire application pool. Also, HttpContext, I believe, is only available with ASP.NET compatibility mode... which, maybe you want, maybe you don't. Message inspectors would help you intercept the inputs (inc. un/pw), but won't directly help solve your problem of getting access to that information from the service code any more than what you have now will.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your third party library wasn't actually built for WCF, and you need to implement the WCF Authorization/Authentication bits?

Have you looked into something like this:

http://www.leastprivilege.com/CustomPrincipalsAndWCF.aspx

You could set Thread.CurrentPrincipal?

Comment: Yes, third party is not build for WCF. At the moment looking at solutions based on customizing IAuthorizationPolicy. One thing is certain - UserNamePasswordValidator is a bad place to create my session. Still searching for a good solution.

Comment: What does "MySession" represent? I assumed it was identity information.

Comment: MySession is a class from third party API that is initialized with username and password and later can be used to retrieve data. Naturally, I don't want to create two MySession objects for each call into my service.

Comment: Can you create a custom IPrincipal, and embed that object in there? Then you could retrieve it later via (Thread.CurrentPrincipal as MyCustomPrincipal).MySession - you'd probably want to wrap that up into a static method on MySession - MySession.GetCurrent()